# Is there a way to free memory of a data container (ctable bcolz) in Python?

Tags: memory, slurm, bcolz

I am using *SLURM* to run a deep learning framework. I am trying to integrate different data containers to this framework (hdf5, bcolz (ctable) and zarr).

When running the framework using ctable as a data structure I got an **error**

> "slurmstepd: error: Exceeded step memory limit at some point".

I think the problem is that when reading a ctable, there is not a function `ctable.close()` that aims to save memory.

Does anyone have an idea how to free memory in this case ?

I tried `self.free_cachemem()` but it doesn't help.

Thank you.